# ¿Cómo conectar Twitter con Java?

Tags: java, twitter-api, twitter

Tengo un pequeño problema con un programa que me dejaron en la universidad, el cual tiene que conectarse con Twitter y Java. He buscado en internet y los tutos que aparecen están un poco desactualizados. La mayoría de los códigos y librerías ya están como caducadas. El programa es de escritorio.

El problema del proyecto no es que se loguee con twitter, sino que lea los tweets de la universidad y me lo muestre.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Se que hay que utilizar los token desde el `apps.twitter.com` ¿pero cómo hago eso?

Comment: Lo primero que deberías hacer es aprender a usar las [librerías de Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries). Es más, incluso te muestran que hay 2 librerías para Java. Aprende a usarlas y busca cómo implementar la funcionalidad que necesitas con esas librerías.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, lo que quieres hacer se puede lograr independientemente del IDE que utilices. Da igual si usas Eclipse, si usas Netbeans, etc.

Ahora respondiendo tu pregunta:

El token de acceso que desees obtener dependerá de lo que quieras hacer, según la [página oficial de Twitter para desarrolladores](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview).
Si navegas un poco por la página encontrarás hay dos librerías que puedes usar en Java para usar la API de Twitter. Por si no encontraste el link te lo dejo [aquí](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries).

Te nombro también una librería de autenticación OAuth llamada [ScribeJava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) que integra autenticación para muchas APIs (incluída la de Twitter). Pero como lo tuyo es específicamente y únicamente para trabajar con Twitter te recomiendo los dos primeros enlaces que te he nombrado.

Comment: yo e estado viendo la documentacion pero no he podido me genera error esta es la primera vez que tengo que conectar mi programa con internet no se si podrias pasar un codigo de como hacer la conexion

Comment: @JhonnyLuis En este momento no tengo un ejemplo sino lo hubiera puesto en la respuesta. Sería bueno que añadas más detalles en la pregunta, incluyendo el error que dices que te genera y algo de código donde aparente estar el problema.